# image not showing on frontend in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I think this question has seen a number of times here in this site itself. But this question is little different, I think so.. :D

I have added some products to my magento site via csv bulk image upload. everything went well. When I looked at my backend of magento, it was all ok, all mandatory fields and required values has filled. But product image was not uploading.
After redoing many times, I went to my backend

> catalog > manage products > product > categories >

And checked on any other categories and saved the products. Now it appears on frontend. Means my product category is A. In bulk product method, it was enabled. still product not showing on front end. And when I Click on any other category such as B, the image showing front end.
Why is it so? Can anyone please help?

Comment: have you try reindexing of data and clear cache?

Comment: yup.. I have tried that also. But it didn't make any difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep upload your product image while import. make sure all product images are under media/import path. if in excel you product image url is e/f/efect.jpg then the product image should be there in media/import/e/f/efect.jpg this path before import.